# Excel Macro Auto Activate

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro enabled workbook called `import`.  When it opens a macro automatically runs; its main job is to import text files into each worksheet of a new workbook (this new workbook is called `book1`).

I have another macro that I required to run on `book1` called `runall`.
Is it possible to configure Excel so that `runall` will then be activated when `book1` is enabled?

Currently I have to go back into the original workbook called `import` and on the  Developer tab activate `runall`.

What I have tried -
In the `import` workbook I have the following code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Call CombineTextFiles
```

I have tried putting `Call runall` in the Private statement.

Comment: Well your application is bound to run upon `Workbook_Open()`. Just call the procedure? `Call runall` ? I don't understand what shouldn't work about it

Comment: Also make sure your code is located in `ThisWorkbook` module, else it won't fire

Comment: I've edited the text of the question.  I'm pretty sure it hasn't changed the meaning of the question - roll back if it has.  As @Rawrplus said - you should just be able to add `runall` on a new line after `CombineTextFiles`.  There's no need for the `Call` keyword - it should work without it.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of events you can tie your code to. One of them is Sheet Activate. In Book1 you can place the following code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
     runall
End Sub
```